# Android Account Manager, is there any callback when user remove account in "Accounts & sync" menu

Tags: android, accountmanager

We are using android account manager to manage account.

As you know, user can remove account from "Accounts & sync" menu.

Is there any callback when user do it ? (app not running)

We want to do something (ex, send token invalied to server, clean DB) when user logout.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `BroadcastReceiver`:

```
public class MyBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        final String action = intent.getAction();

        // start the SimlessMainService and set an Action Tag
        Intent yourServiceToHandleThisIntent = new Intent(context, YourServiceToHandleThis.class);
        if ( android.accounts.AccountManager.LOGIN_ACCOUNTS_CHANGED_ACTION.equals(action) ) {
            yourServiceToHandleThisIntent .setAction(Constants.ACTION_LOGIN_ACCOUNTS_CHANGED);
        }
        context.startService(yourServiceToHandleThisIntent );
    }   
}
```

And in the `Manifest.xml`:

```
<application>
...
  <receiver
            android:name=".MyBroadcastReceiver "
            android:enabled="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.accounts.LOGIN_ACCOUNTS_CHANGED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
...
</application>
```